# trying to create a general purpose functions that make an array of any type and store the size at [-1], return size function, and freearray function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//general function that can create an array of any kind and then hide the size of it at[-1].
void * createArray(int n, int dataTypeSize);
//returns the size from location [-1] of array
void getArraySize(void * array);
//frees array 
void freeArray(void * array);

int main(void){
    double * array=0;
    int size=10;
    array=createArray(size,sizeof(double));
    if(array==NULL){
        printf("\nmemory could not be allocated");
    }
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        array[i]=i;
        printf("%lf",array[i]);
    }
    printf("\nsize of the array is %lf",getArraySize(array));
    freeArray(array);

}
void * createArray(int n,int dataTypeSize){
    void * array=0;
    array=malloc(n*dataTypeSize+sizeof(int));
    if(array==NULL){
        printf("\nmemory could not be allocated");
        exit(0);
    }
    //moves array up 1
    array=array+1;
    //changes size to the specified datatype and stores it at -1
    array[-1]=(dataTypeSize)n;
    return(array);
}

void getArraySize(void * array){
    return(array[-1]);
}

void freeArray(void * array){
    free(array-1);
}
```

I am having a hard time trying to make this all purpose. The problems I am currently running into are in the createArray function where I try to change the size integer to the specified datatypesize so I can store it at -1

.testlab3.c: In function 'createArray':

testlab3.c:36:7: error: dereferencing 'void *' pointer [-Werror]
array[-1]=(dataTypeSize)n;
^

testlab3.c:36:11: error: invalid use of void expression
array[-1]=(dataTypeSize)n;
^

testlab3.c:36:26: error: expected ';' before 'n'
array[-1]=(dataTypeSize)n;
^
;

testlab3.c: In function 'getArraySize':

testlab3.c:41:14: error: dereferencing 'void *' pointer [-Werror]
return(array[-1]);
^

cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors

The next thing is when i try to print the size (in main) it said invalid use of void expression.
just starting to code, so any help will be appreciated. Im confused on the use of void for general purpose functions, so anything about that would help also!

Comment: As the msg says, you can't dereference a void pointer. The compiler can't know what size the data is in that case. You can cast to `int *` first. `array=array+1;` is also wrong because pointer arithmetic on void pointers is not allowed in the C standard. GNU gcc does allow it but even then it's still wrong as it will treat it as size 1 wheres you need to increment by the size of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cant use the index `-1` as it is out of bounds

You should use struct for that.

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t elementsize;
    unsigned char data[];
}data_t;


data_t *create(size_t size, size_t elementSize)
{
    data_t *data = malloc(sizeof(*data) + size * elementSize);

    if(data)
    {
        data -> size = size;
        data -> elementsize = elementSize;
    }
    return data;
}

void destroy(data_t *data)
{
    free(data);
}
```

For sizes you should use the correct type `size_t`.

Comment: The OP has done `array=array+1;` before that `-1` index. It's still wrong but the intention is to have the `array` pointer start one `int` into the actual allocated buffer. Similar to how many `malloc` implementations put a header before data blocks.

Comment: @kaylum what does this `+1` do in your opinion?

Comment: It doesn't work as intended in my opinion. I'm just explaining what it appears the OP's intention is.

Comment: Explain what does it do on `void *`

Comment: It's invalid according to the C standard but gcc supports that by treating it as +1 to the address.

Comment: lets consider gcc. we add 1 then substract 4 (in bytes) and dereference it - any good?

Comment: i was trying to move the memory address so i could store the size at array[-1]. should i put the value of size in first before I move the address? This was something I was taught in class. thats why i added the extra int in malloc.

Comment: It's not subtracting 4, it's subtracting 1. Because `array` is `void *` so `array[-1]` is subtracting 1. So it's not technically out of bounds but wrong for other reasons.